# How to make a directory inaccessible with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried  to put a `.htaccess` file in the given directory but it doesn't seem to work over a remote webserver. It works fine in WAMP on my computer.

```
deny from all 
order deny,allow
Limit GET, POST
```

I want to make the `Getthefiles` directory inaccessible from this url:

```
http://pmln-hec.site88.net/Getthefiles/
```

The apache version is 2.2.19, hosted with 000webhost.

Comment: This syntax only works for apache 2.2 and the virtual host must allow override. You can try `require all denied` if it's 2.4

Comment: If you are using `000webhosts` as your title originally claimed, [this blog post](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaches-traders-plain-text-passwords/) may be of great interest to you

Comment: @Martin good point, I overlooked the hosting company's pertinence. It's back in.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is a little wrong, if you want to do it for a specific file, then you can use this:

```
<Files Getthefiles.html>
order deny,allow
allow from [your IP goes here]
deny from all
</Files>
```

So this will still allow access from your own IP to this directory, and then deny access to everyone else.

Another option is that you can password protect that directory.